# ERROR: Preparation failed: Unable to communicate with the remote host, since it is disconnected

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm seeing this error when trying to create a package.  Is it temporary, relating to an internal process in creating a new VM?

The actual error is as follows:
Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0~beta.147.gbd1f3fcb (bd1f3fcb)
  on ip-10-2-50-102 (815cf240)
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Unable to communicate with the remote host, since it is disconnected.
Will be retried in 3s ...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Unable to communicate with the remote host, since it is disconnected.
Will be retried in 3s ...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Unable to communicate with the remote host, since it is disconnected.
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Unable to communicate with the remote host, since it is disconnected.

Comment: And how is this related to ionic ?

Comment: It was seen during the package building process within Ionic Pro.  I know longer see it, though, so I assume it was the VM.